# How can I make the following test template?

Tags: books, mathematics

How can I make this template in the most correct way?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please show us what you have tried so far! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: If you neglect the round corners and those horizontal spaces bteween the bluish lines and areas, it's just a table with some colored lines in it. If you need those rounded corners and the spaces a way to do it is superimposing a drawing, e.g. from package pstricks. // Looking forward to your trial code ;-)

Comment: Okey I am trying :)

Comment: I added the code. I tried to make something but it didn't look like the pictures :(

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you could share the solution with us. Otherwise the question doesn't make sense you could delete it ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow My guess is that is relates to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614543/118712