# How can I re-define a fraction line?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to redefine by increasing the width of the fraction line.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$\dfrac{x+y}{x^2-y^2}$\hspace{1cm}$\dfrac{\;\;\;x+y\;\;\;}{x^2-y^2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd not use `\dfrac` in inline math normally, but you can define your own command `\newcommand\myfrac[2]{\dfrac{\;#1\;}{\;#2\;}}`

Comment: Yes it worked. Really amazing thank you:)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you help me with this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614343/how-can-i-make-the-following-test-template?noredirect=1#comment1534744_614343

Comment: @cufcuf that's not how the site works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd not use `\dfrac` in inline math normally, but you can define your own command `\newcommand\myfrac[2]{\dfrac{\;#1\;}{\;#2\;}}`  (or better use `\frac` in the definition)

Comment: Yes i used ```\frac``` in the definition thanks