# Formatting the rectangle in the page title

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, multicol

There are some things I want to be arranged as seen in the images below Original rectangle:

[image]
I want this: (The colors in the corners don't matter.)
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.misc}

\newcommand\around{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw[line width=2.1pt] {[rounded corners=0] ($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-4cm)$) --  ++(0,2cm) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-2cm)$)} -- ++(0,-2cm) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=yellow,line width=2.1pt] {[rounded corners=15] ($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-2cm)$) --  ++(0,1cm) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-15cm,-1cm)$)} -- ++(0,-1cm) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=yellow,line width=2.1pt] {[rounded corners=15] ($(current page.north west)+(+15cm,-2cm)$) --  ++(0,1cm) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-1cm)$)} -- ++(0,-1cm) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=yellow,line width=2.1pt] {[rounded corners=0] ($(current page.north west)+(+6.3cm,-2cm)$) --  ++(0,1cm) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-6.3cm,-1cm)$)} -- ++(0,-1cm) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{3cm}
}
\begin{document}
    \around
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an answer to a similar question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118786/118712 (Note, that I am NOT refering to the accepted answer, but the other one by user Holi) Maybe you can adapt that code to your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a node like this can be a bit tricky, as is evident from many solutions to similar questions like to one I linked to in the comments. It is probably easier to default to drawing the actual rectangle manually using `rounded corners`, like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\around{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw[line width=2.1pt] {[rounded corners=15] ($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-4cm)$) --  ++(0,3cm) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-1cm)$)} -- ++(0,-3cm) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{3cm}
}

\begin{document}
    \around
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Based on your new question you can do this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\around{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,line width=2.1pt]
        \draw ($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-4cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-2cm)$);
    
        \draw[fill=yellow] {[rounded corners=15] ($(current page.north west)+(1cm,-2cm)$) -- ++(0,1cm)} -- ++(5cm,0) -- ++(0,-1cm) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=yellow] {[rounded corners=15] ($(current page.north east)+(-1cm,-2cm)$) -- ++(0,1cm)} -- ++(-5cm,0) -- ++(0,-1cm) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=yellow] ($(current page.north)+(-4cm,-2cm)$) -- ++(0,1cm) -- ($(current page.north)+(4cm,-1cm)$) -- ++(0,-1cm) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{3cm}
}
\begin{document}
    \around
\end{document}
```

Note that it is extremely bad practice to load packages more than once and that `tikz` automatically loads `graphicx`.

Comment: I made something new thanks to your code. I edited my code can you comment it now?

Comment: @cufcuf I added a revised answer.

Comment: Very thanks for your interest and help. @Markus G.

Comment: One last thing, how can I write text inside each rectangle?